# git push origin head?

Tags: git

I had made some changes to a file under a git repo, I committed the files using `git commit`

I then tried to push to master using `git push origin master` which returned `Everything up-to-date`

I typed `git push origin head` which seemed to work although I'm not sure if I'm supposed to do this. Previously `git push origin head` had always worked for me.

My question is, why would `git push origin master` not do anything and should I roll back and re-commit, then `git push origin master`?

Comment: Are you working in the local master branch or a branch tracking master? Is the remote repo using master as the main branch (the actually selected branch when you clone)?

Comment: I'm trying to work from a dev branch on my local and live branch on the public-facing server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're working on a development branch, then `git push origin master` isn't going to do anything because you've asked it to push the `master` branch.  If you want to push your development branch, you need to run:

```
git push origin development
```

...or whatever you've called your development branch.  And after doing that once, you should generally be able to run `git push` without additional arguments.

Comment: *“`git push origin master` isn't going to do anything”* – Not true. It should push to the remote’s master.

Comment: ...not if he's been working on a development branch and left the master branch unmodified.