# What does git push origin HEAD mean?

Tags: git, git-push

I found, in the [official guide](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-push):

> `git push origin HEAD`
>
> A handy way to push the current branch to the
> same name on the remote.

However, the meaning of the command is not clear to me. Why does it have this effect?

I haven't been able to find an answer ([this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11731414/git-push-origin-head) seems to treat the problem, but the title is misleading).

Answer (score 207, accepted):

`HEAD` points to the top of the current branch. `git` can obtain the branch name from that. So it's the same as:

```
git push origin CURRENT_BRANCH_NAME
```

but you don't have to remember/type the current branch name. Also it prevents you from pushing to the wrong remote branch by accident.

If you want to push a different branch than the current one the command will not work.

Comment: It might help to mention that `HEAD` is a symbolic ref, and it can be seen with `git symbolic-ref HEAD`.

Comment: What is the difference between: `git push origin` and `git push origin HEAD`?

Comment: @MaciejD git push origin without specifying a branch name doesn't work.  either you add a branch name or you say HEAD, meaning the current branch you're in

Comment: Actually `git push origin` is a valid command. If the `push.default` Git config setting is set to `nothing` then `git push origin` will "not push anything (error out)" according to `man git-config`. But other `push.default` settings have other behaviors. Search for `push.default` in `man git-config`. Also search for "When the command line does not specify **where** to push" and "When the command line does not specify **what** to push" in the description section at the top of `man git-push` (that's `man git-push`, not `man git-config`).

Answer (score 24):

If you want to push into the specific remote branch you can run:

```
git push origin HEAD:<name-of-remote-branch>
```

This is what I encounter when I was trying to push my repo back to the remote branch.