# Difference between git push origin development and git push origin HEAD:development

Tags: git

after some weeks using git as a machine, now I'm on my way to figure out how GIT really works. Than I started with a simple thing:

```
git checkout -b test origin/development`   //Creating new local branch from development

Create new text file called test.txt

git add . //Set files that will be committed
git commit -m "this is a test" // Committing
```

And then comes my doubt:

When I try to push doing:

```
git push origin development
```

The log says: Everything is up to date

If I try to push doing:

```
git push origin HEAD:development
```

It works as it should.

Doing my research I found that HEAD means the name of the current branch. So, if it is right, it doesn't make any sense to me.

What is the difference between

```
git push origin development
```

and

```
git push origin HEAD:development
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [git push origin head?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11731414/git-push-origin-head)

Comment: It is not, @Basilevs. He is asking the difference between push to origin master and origin head. I'm asking the difference between origin master and origin HEAD:master.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
git push remote-name some-name
```

attempts to push any *local* branch named `some-name` to a remote branch *also* named `some-name` resolved at `remote-name/some-name`. Under the hood, it's looking for branch names under `refs` at each location (local, remote) that match.

Since your local copy of `development` hasn't been modified, you get a message that it's up to date, nothing to push.

The alternate version

```
git push remote-name HEAD:development
```

skips the part about looking for matching branch names in local and remote `refs` because you've given it an explicit branch via `HEAD`.

It still does use remote `refs` to determine the remote branch `development`. But then it uses `HEAD` of the current branch (your new `test` branch) for the commits to be pushed.

If you want to simply do `git push` from `test` branch and correctly push from `test` to `remote/development`, you can configure the default behavior of `push` to the "upstream" setting (note that the term "tracking" is an older term for "upstream" which is preferred).

Do

```
git config --global push.default upstream
```

to ensure that a plain `git push` will only attempt to push from the current branch to its registered upstream branch.

Without the setting, prior to git version 2.0, the default mode for a plain `git push` results in attempting to push *all* local branches to upstream branches with matching names at their configured remotes. For git 2.0 and newer, the default setting is `simple` which acts like `upstream` except that it also fails to push if the current branch doesn't share the same name as its configured remote.

The "upstream" setting is a good one because (a) it allows easily pushing branches regardless of whether their names match to their upstream names; (b) for versions prior to 2.0, it restricts a bare invocation of `git push` to affecting only the current branch, so if you're actively developing on multiple branches, `git push` will no longer unintentionally push other work unrelated to current branch work; (c) you will not need the form of git push that specifically names the remote and branch unless you're attempting to push to some branch that is not the configured upstream for your current branch -- and I'd argue this makes the most sense: you should only need to verbosely spell out the branches if you're not pushing from a local branch to its natural, configured upstream target. Even the 2.0 `simple` setting doesn't satisfy this.

`remote-name` is often `origin`, but can be any configured remote, added via various git commands or directly as in a .gitconfig file.

Comment: Git changed the default setting for push with version 2.0 a while back, you are describing 1.9 and older.

Comment: Updated to describe the `simple` default in git 2.0.

Answer (score 3):

`git push origin development` pushes `development` branch

`git push origin HEAD:development` pushes current branch to remote's `development`

Most likely you are not in local `development` branch. Consider checking this with

```
git status
```

command.

Answer (score 0):

`git push origin development`

will try to push your local development branch. By this type of `git push` command, git will think local branch and remote tracking branch have the same branch nanme.

From manpage of git push

`git push origin master
     Find a ref that matches master in the source repository (most likely, it would find refs/heads/master), and update the same ref (e.g.  refs/heads/master) in origin repository with it. If master did not exist remotely, it would be created.`

Comment: I got the functionality of GIT PUSH, my question is about the difference between push to HEAD:BRANCH and push to BRANCH.

Comment: @RodrigoBorba This question is about syntax of git command, the difference has been defined in manpage.